# Replication with MySQL 5.6 as the master and 5.7 as the slave

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.6, mysql-5.7

When trying to do replication with 5.6 as the master and 5.7 as the slave, after `source dump.sql` I entered this;

`mysql> CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST="<MASTER_HOSTNAME>", MASTER_USER="slave_user", MASTER_PASSWORD="password", MASTER_AUTO_POSITION = 1;`

obviously I changed  to an actual hostname, I got the following error;

`ERROR 1805 (HY000): Column count of mysql.slave_relay_log_info is wrong. Expected 9, found 8. The table is probably corrupted`

Is this a problem with using 5.6 as the master and 5.7 as the slave?
I have tried the dump several times with the same error. Although is says it's supported here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-compatibility.html

Comment: which exact versions of mysql 5.6 and 5.7 are you using?

Comment: Master - mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.33, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper. Slave - mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.16, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Answer (score 2):

Drop the `mysql.slave_relay_log_info` table on the 5.7 slave. Log out of mysql, run `mysql_upgrade -uroot -p -s` to recreate the dropped table. Log back in to mysql instance then `stop slave` / `start slave` all should be good.

The problem was when you source dump.sql it somehow changed the table definition in 5.7 hence the error you were getting.

A simple test I tried was on a working 5.6 master to 5.7 slave repl, I dropped the `slave_relay_log_info` table on 5.7 and recreated it with 5.6's table structure and got the same error when I started slave replication.

```
mysql [localhost] {msandbox} ((none)) > use mysql;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql [localhost] {msandbox} (mysql) > CREATE TABLE `slave_relay_log_info` (
    ->   `Number_of_lines` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Number of lines in the file or rows in the table. Used to version table definitions.',
    ->   `Relay_log_name` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL COMMENT 'The name of the current relay log file.',
    ->   `Relay_log_pos` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The relay log position of the last executed event.',
    ->   `Master_log_name` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL COMMENT 'The name of the master binary log file from which the events in the relay log file were read.',
    ->   `Master_log_pos` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The master log position of the last executed event.',
    ->   `Sql_delay` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'The number of seconds that the slave must lag behind the master.',
    ->   `Number_of_workers` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    ->   `Id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Internal Id that uniquely identifies this record.',
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 STATS_PERSISTENT=0 COMMENT='Relay Log Information';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

mysql [localhost] {msandbox} (mysql) > start slave;
ERROR 1805 (HY000): Column count of mysql.slave_relay_log_info is wrong. Expected 9, found 8. The table is probably corrupted
```

---

EDIT:
You can drop the table with the wrong structure, and recreate it with this:

```
CREATE TABLE `mysql`.`slave_relay_log_info` (
  `Number_of_lines` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Number of lines in the file or rows in the table. Used to version table definitions.',
  `Relay_log_name` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL COMMENT 'The name of the current relay log file.',
  `Relay_log_pos` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The relay log position of the last executed event.',
  `Master_log_name` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL COMMENT 'The name of the master binary log file from which the events in the relay log file were read.',
  `Master_log_pos` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The master log position of the last executed event.',
  `Sql_delay` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'The number of seconds that the slave must lag behind the master.',
  `Number_of_workers` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Internal Id that uniquely identifies this record.',
  `Channel_name` char(64) NOT NULL COMMENT 'The channel on which the slave is connected to a source. Used in Multisource Replication',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Channel_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 STATS_PERSISTENT=0 COMMENT='Relay Log Information';
```

Comment: `The --upgrade-system-tables option was used, databases won't be touched.`
`Checking if update is needed.`
`Checking server version.`
`Running queries to upgrade MySQL server.`
`The sys schema is already up to date (version 1.5.1).`
`Found 0 sys functions, but expected 22. Re-installing the sys schema.`
`Upgrading the sys schema.`
`Upgrade process completed successfully.`
`Could not create the upgrade info file '/var/lib/mysql/mysql_upgrade_info' in the MySQL Servers datadir, errno: 13`

Comment: was the problematic table re-created with the correct table structure? you can also try my other suggestion. regarding errno: 13 it could be that the system user you ran mysql_upgrade didn't have write privs on the datadir.

Comment: I ran it as root. Sorry I'm more sysadmin than DBA. Which `mysqldump` options should I use on the master on 5.6?

Comment: i don't think you missed anything, but i think mysql_upgrade should check and update the system tables accordingly

Comment: My other option is to create a new server with 5.7 on it and copy the data across and upgrade in place before I make it 'live' for the customer. Is this easier?

Comment: @eekfonky did you mean setup a 5.6 dump the master there and upgrade inplace? it'll work. but the one you have now just needs slave_relay_log_info table fixed and you should be good to go

Comment: I'll try it and get back to you - maybe Monday though as it's Friday! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you file a bug at http://bugs.mysql.com

It seems that the problem has to do with:

```
`Channel_name` char(64) NOT NULL COMMENT 'The channel on which the slave is connected to a source. Used in Multisource Replication'
```

in the 5.7 version of `mysql.slave_relay_log_info`, but not in 5.6.

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=82384 suggests that `mysql.slave_master_info` has trouble, too.